# download youtube mp4 then upload to aws s3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

laravel 5.1 project here, i'm already uploading images to s3 using intervention, but now i want to upload a youtube video to a folder in s3 in mp4 format.

Putting youtube video url and then hitting upload button, and voila, video is now in s3 and saved the s3 url in mysql db for posterior use.

Comment: ok, so what/where is your problem exactly?

Comment: You cannot upload it directly, it's a 2 steps process; You'll have to download the video then upload it to s3 ... there are many packages that can help you download from youtube just lookup a good one in packagist.org

Comment: yes, but i want to download to my server, all the php projects out there, will download the video to my pc, not to a folder in the server